# How can I leave a link in history by assigning window.location?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-history

I am writing a web with javascript. I want to redirect the user to specific page.

```
http://examplesite.com/current_page -> http://examplesite.com/final_page
```

Here I write

```
window.location = 'http://examplesite.com/final_page';
```

But I also want add a link between current_page and final_page in browser session history. Then I write

```
window.location = 'http://examplesite.com/middle_page';
window.location = 'http://examplesite.com/final_page';
```

I want the browser history be

```
/current_page -> /middle_page -> /final_page
```

Then when user click "previous page" button in /final_page, she will go back to /middle_page first. Unfortunately, it appears assign to location twice doesn't work. The /middle_page does not appear in history. How can I add the middle_page in history then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**first page:**

```
window.location = 'http://examplesite.com/middle_page';
```

**middle_page:**

```
window.location = 'http://examplesite.com/final_page';
```

When you browse to first page, you will redirected to middle_page, who will redirect you to final_page.

Comment: Of course I can do that, but once the user goes back to middle, she will be redirected to the final_page then. I want them to be able to stay at middle_page.

Answer (score 1):

On firefox 4+, they have the [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) where you can add entries to the history.

You can also [embed iframes](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs#A_quick_summary_of_the_IFrame-URL_technique) and use the iframe to add entries to the history. Changing the location of the iframe will be noted in the history.

you can use either technique to pop-in that middle page. but each has it's own quirks.